# Nilpotency of BRST operator in gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, curvature, brst, ghosts

I am going through the BRST quantisation in Perturbative quantum gravity and looked at the papers of Nishijima and Ojima. I am confused about the closure of the BRST operator; I.e  $s^2=0$, particularly in the case of the ghost field.

The BRST transform of the ghost field is:
$$sc^{\mu} = c^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}c^{\mu}$$

Therefore, $$s^2c^{\mu}= sc^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}c^{\mu}-c^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}sc^{\mu}\\= c^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}c^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}c^{\mu}-c^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}c^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}c^{\mu}-c^{\lambda}c^{\nu}\nabla_{\lambda}\nabla_{\nu}c^{\mu}\\=- c^{\lambda}c^{\nu}\nabla_{\lambda}\nabla_{\nu}c^{\mu} $$

So I find $s^2 c^{\mu}$ is not vanishing here. What mistake am I doing here?

Here is the link of the paper by Nishijima:
https://doi.org/10.1143/PTP.60.272

The particular equation numbers are: 2.25 and 2.26, in page number 275.

Answer (score 5):

The anticommutativity of the $c$'s means  expression is a commutator
$$
c^\lambda c^\nu \nabla_\lambda\nabla_\nu c^\mu=\frac 12 (c^\lambda c^\nu-c^\nu c^\lambda)\nabla_\lambda\nabla_\nu  c^\mu\\
= \frac 12  c^\lambda c^\nu [\nabla_\lambda, \nabla_\nu] c^\mu\\
 =
\frac 12  c^\lambda c^\nu  {R^\mu}_{\alpha\lambda \nu}c^\alpha\\
=\frac 12  c^\alpha c^\lambda  c^\nu {R^\mu}_{\alpha\lambda \nu}
$$
which vanishes (for torsion free) by the first Bianchi identity.

Comment: The later part, i.e the vanishing of the expression due to Bianchi identity I understand. But how is the commutator appearing?

Comment: I'll add material.

Comment: Thanks. Yes a little elaboration of the steps would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear now.